# If $S=TX$, then $\sigma\{S_1,\ldots,S_n\}=\sigma\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $S=(S_1,\ldots,S_n)$ and $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be two random vectors, and let $T=(T_1,\ldots,T_n):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear bijective map. Suppose that $S=TX$. How can I prove that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ is the same as $X_1,\ldots,X_n$?

For instance, if $B$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$, I have $S_i^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}(T_i^{-1}(B))$, but I do not know how to show that $X^{-1}(T_i^{-1}(B))\in\sigma\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fact 1: A linear map on a finite dimensional space is continuous.

Fact 2: If $f$ is a continuous map, and $G$ is an open subset of the range then $f^{-1}(G)$ is an open subset of the domain.

Fact 3: If a bijection $f$ is linear, so is $f^{-1}$.

Fact 4: For any collection of sets $\mathcal{C}$, and for any function $f$, $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{C})) = \sigma(f^{-1}(C))$.

---

Denote by $\tau$ the collection of all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and denote by $\mathcal{B}$ the Borel field on $\mathbb{R}^n$. By definition of $\mathcal{B}$, $\mathcal{B} = \sigma(\tau)$. By facts 1-3, $T^{-1}(\tau) = \tau$. Therefore
$$
S^{-1}(\mathcal{B}) = X^{-1}\left(T^{-1}(\sigma(\tau))\right) \overset{\text{Fact 4}}{=} X^{-1}\left(\sigma(T^{-1}(\tau))\right) = X^{-1}(\sigma(\tau)) = X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}).
$$

Comment: Is the fact that $S^{-1}(\mathcal{B})=X^{-1}(\mathcal{B})$ equivalent to $$\sigma\{S_i^{-1}(B):i=1,\ldots,n,\,B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}=\sigma\{X_i^{-1}(B):i=1,\ldots,n,\,B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}\,?$$

Comment: @user372906: Yes, indeed. By the way, I see that you're a new user here. You may not be aware that you can upvote answers as a way of saying "thank you" by clicking on the double up-arrow, and that you can additionally indicate an answer as satisfactory by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: And how is the proof of that?

Comment: @user372906: I suggest you post a new question for that. And thanks for marking my answer.